# Is there a way to import Jest globals?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In the [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html), it mentions that the main API is added as globals to every test file. Is there some way to import these instead, or are you forced to use globals? That feels very 2010js. :)

Comment: In addition, there are problems with linting tools, such as `standardjs`. The only way to make `.test.js` files lintable is by adding `/* eslint-disable no-undef */` rule at the top of the file... which is not very nice.

Comment: Welp, this is a lot more complicated than it looks.  As far as I can tell, the `jest` object is assembled dynamically by the `jest-runtime` submodule.  And that is tightly coupled with a whole host of things like config, the runtime environment, the filesystem, and a number of other things.  My conclusion: One does not simply `import jest from "jest"`